# Simple static methods (Console) help

Tags: c#, static-methods

this is my first time posting my problem here, i hope i get help :)

My Problem:

I am trying to display the "This Old Man" (first two stanzas only) in the Console.
I am beginning to learn methods, so please bear my n00bishness.

The Song goes:

```
This old man, he played one
He played knick−knack on my thumb
With a knick−knack paddy−whack
Give a dog a bone
This old man came rolling home


This old man, he played two
He played knick−knack on my shoe
With a knick−knack paddy−whack
Give a dog a bone
This old man came rolling home
```

---

I coded the following:

```
namespace Song
{
    class Song
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            doVerse(1);
            doChorus();
        }
        static void doChorus()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("With a knick−knack paddy−whack");
            Console.WriteLine("Give the dog a bone");
            Console.WriteLine("This old man came rolling home");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void doVerse(int verseNum)
        {
            string message = "";
            message += "This old man, he played ";
            message += verseNum;
            message += ". \nHe played knick−knack ";
            //message += getPlace(verseNum);
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
        static void getPlace()
        {
            string message = "";
            switch (verseNum)
            {
                case 1:
                    message = "on my thumb ";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    message = "on my shoe";
                    break;
                default:
                    message = "not yet defined";
                    break;
            }
            return message;
        }
    }
}
```

Visual studio is giving me the following errors:

http://i56.tinypic.com/fx850m.jpg

I hope you guys understand my intention with this program.

Thanks

Regards,

Kyle :D

Comment: Looks like `getPlace` needs `int verseNum` as a parameter

Comment: ♫ This old man, he played 2147483647, He played knick-knack not yet defined... ♫

Comment: Anyway, you should start changing: 
`static void getPlace()` 
to:
`static string getPlace(int verseNum)`

Comment: homework? no its not! i am trying to learn this on my own before school starts so i can improve.

The question is....what is missing in the code?

If you don't know please don't mind replying

thanks

Comment: Heh, posting here is a bit like walking into the tiger pit, but sometimes the tigers are cuddly.

You need to define getPlace with something like "static string getPlace()" so you cna return the string value.

Comment: @Jaydee - if questions like these are too easy for users here, i won't post again. sorry

Comment: @kylebriffa7, don't stop posting questions because you think someone will say it is too easy. we all had to start somewhere.

Comment: @kyle: everyone start learning from easy things (excluding Jon Skeet maybe), so don't worry about... :)

Comment: It isn't a question of it being too easy Kyle, but if you look through some of the questions you'll see some that basically post a homework question and expect an answer "ASAP". You seem to have actually thought about what you are trying to achieve. By the way did you think of creating an array items[1]="thumb", items[2]="shoe" etc. then get items[verseNum]

Comment: thanks Jaydee for your response and yeah i see your point.

I will try to create the array. thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `getPlace` method to this:

```
static string getPlace(int verseNum)
{
    string message = "";
    switch (verseNum)
    {
        case 1:
            message = "on my thumb ";
            break;
        case 2:
            message = "on my shoe";
            break;
        default:
            message = "not yet defined";
            break;
    }
    return message;
}
```

<s>I'm guessing this is homework,</s> so I'll explain why it wasn't working. You had two errors:

1. You're method was set to `static void`
   and you were trying to return a
   `string`. You had to replace `void`
   with `string` to indicate that the
   method returns a `string`.
2. You were using a
   variable called `verseNum` which was
   not present in the method. To pass
   in the variable you have to include
   it within the method signature.

Comment: Thanks GenericTypeTea! Worked!

i am beggining to grab hold of these now :)

Comment: btw this is NOT homework :\ why everyone is saying that?

i am trying to learn from various sites ON MY OWN so as school starts i'll be familiar with these, that's all :\

Comment: Because usually people are lazy and do nothing if not forced by homework's duty. Thus the supposition. Don't worry about it ;)

Comment: @kylebriffa7 - A lot of us have obviously been through the whole leaning process at schools and with workbooks, and questions such as this do appear like workbook excercises. Don't take it personally. If it's not homework, no need to worry. People just get arsy about helping with homework as we don't want to do the work for them, we want to HELP them understand what they need to do instead.